# reading a text file using python problems with float

Tags: python, file

I have a text file that has lines like this(file is called "copyFile"):

```
81 ARG A  -77.15  137.28  179.59  -60.26  175.90   59.45   98.78
```

if I do

```
for line in open('copyFile'):
    print line
```

works perfectly

if I do

```
print line[12:18]
```

works as well

prints `-77.15`

but if I want to capture the same this like `float(line[12:18])`

the code seems to be reading some other file. Am I doing something wrong?

I tried using the "split" command as well, same issue

Comment: yes you are doing something wrong.  Its hard to say what with the little you have given us

Comment: Can you post complete code? Context is likely to be very important.

Comment: And in addition to the code, show the unexpected output; just saying "… seems to be reading some other file" makes it very hard to guess what it's actually doing.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `print open('copyFile')[12:18]`?

Comment: It looks like, with the file output you've given us, `line[12:18]` should yield `7.15  `, which, when casted into a float will give `7.15`, perhaps you wanted `line[10:17]`?

Comment: @Asad No, because he's iterating through each line

Comment: Try `float(line.split(' ')[4])`

Comment: @Haidro You're right. What's weird here is that getting `[12:18]` as a slice from the OP's string does not yield the output he/she is describing.

Answer (score 0):

[Floating point numbers](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) are not always exact:

```
>>> float('-77.15')
-77.150000000000006
```

You may want to handle them differently (using [Decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) numbers, perhaps).